# I must solve this question on random walk, but I don't know where to start or how to do it (I need a hint)

Tags: econometrics, random-walk

Let $\{y_t: t=1,2,\dots \}$ follow a random walk, as in: $y_t=y_{t-1}+e_t$, with $y_0=0$. Show that Corr$(y_t,y_{t+h} )=\sqrt{t ⁄ (t+h)}$, for $t\ge 1$, $h>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Can you calculate the covariance $Cov(Y_t, Y_{t+h})$?

If not, does it help to note that:
$$Y_{t+h} = Y_t + \underbrace{(e_{t+1}+\dots+e_{t+h})}_{\scriptsize\hbox{ind. of $Y_t$}}$$

Also, don't forget this property of covariances:
$$Cov(U+V,W)=Cov(U,W)+Cov(V,W)$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will try it on my side to work on this!